# unable to run a Grails integration test for webFlow 2.0.0

Tags: grails, spring-webflow, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.0.3 and webFlow 2.0.0.

I have a WebFlow definition in my controller that is working fine but I want to still add integration tests to facilitate future maintenance.

I am getting the following exception in my test whenever the controller attempts to add some value to the flow scope:

```
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.webflow.engine.builder.ClosureInvokingAction  - Exception occured invoking flow action: No such property: poInfo for class: org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: poInfo for class: org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap 
        at com.psswm.inboundcal.ReceivingEventController$_closure1_closure6_closure12.doCall(ReceivingEventController.groovy:83) 
        at grails.test.WebFlowTestCase.signalEvent(WebFlowTestCase.groovy:143) 
        at com.psswm.inboundcal.ReceivingEventCreationFlowTests.testAddPoInfoMissingPiecesPallets(ReceivingEventCreationFlowTests.groovy:32) 
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45) 
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) 
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42) 
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20) 
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28) 
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263) 
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68) 
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) 
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28) 
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) 
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) 
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) 
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) 
        at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:290) 
        at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:248) 
        at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1_closure21.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:195) 
        at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:184) 
        at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:82) 
| Failure:  testAddPoInfoMissingPiecesPallets(com.psswm.inboundcal.ReceivingEventCreationFlowTests) 
|  org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.codehaus.groovy.grails.webflow.engine.builder.ClosureInvokingAction@3beff9ad in state 'addPO' of flow 'create' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]' 
        at grails.test.WebFlowTestCase.signalEvent(WebFlowTestCase.groovy:143) 
        at com.psswm.inboundcal.ReceivingEventCreationFlowTests.testAddPoInfoMissingPiecesPallets(ReceivingEventCreationFlowTests.groovy:32) 
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: poInfo for class: org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap 
        at com.psswm.inboundcal.ReceivingEventController$_closure1_closure6_closure12.doCall(ReceivingEventController.groovy:83) 
        ... 2 more
```

---

This is the part of My WebFlow code that I am trying to test:

```
def createFlow = { 
    initialize { 
        action { 
            if (params.eventId) { 
                flow.receivingEventId = params.eventId as int 
                ReceivingEvent existingReceivingEvent = ReceivingEvent.get(flow.receivingEventId) 
                flow.receivingEvent = new ReceivingEvent(branch:existingReceivingEvent.branch) 
            } 
        } 
        on ("success").to "addPO" 
    } 

    addPO { 
        on("add") { 
            log.debug("addPO") 
            // Initialize flow objects 
            flow.poInfo = new PoInfo(params) 
            if (flow.receivingEvent == null) { 
                flow.receivingEvent = new ReceivingEvent() 
            } 

            // validate and populate poInfo object 
            boolean objectIsValid = flow.poInfo.validateAndPopulate() 
            if(!objectIsValid) { 
                if(!flow.poInfo.hasErrors()) { 
                    flash.warning = 'poInfo.poNumber.unknown' 
                } 
                return error() 
            } 
            // add poInfo object to receivingEvent for additional processing/validation 
            String errorMessage = flow.receivingEvent.addPoInfo(flow.poInfo) 

            if(null != errorMessage) { 
                flash.warning = errorMessage 
                return error() 
            } else { 
                flow.poInfo = null 
            } 
        }.to("addPO")
```

........

---

And this is my integration test:

```
class ReceivingEventCreationFlowTests extends WebFlowTestCase{ 

ReceivingEventController receivingEventController = new ReceivingEventController() 

void testInitializeFlow() { 
    startFlow() 
    assertCurrentStateEquals "addPO" 
} 

void testAddPoInfoMissingPiecesPallets() { 
    println("Hola mundo") 
    startFlow() 
    assertCurrentStateEquals "addPO" 

    receivingEventController.params.poNumber = '63055024UI1063' 
    receivingEventController.params.pro = '3' 
    println "flow scope: " + getFlowScope().getClass() 
    println ("Hola again") 
    signalEvent('add') 
    assertTrue getFlowScope().poInfo.hasErrors() 
    assertCurrentStateEquals "addPO" 
} 

@Override 
public Object getFlow() { 
    receivingEventController.createFlow 
} 

String getFlowId() { "create" } 
}
```

---

Anybody has any ideas on what am I missing here? or if there are any known integration testing issues with webFlow 2.0.0 and grails 2.0.3?

I am following the guidelines from the book:  Grails in Action, chapter 9.4:  Testing WebFlows... and yet I keep getting the above error.

Thanks in advance,

Jorge Vasquez

Answer (score 0):

Grails in Action is a very good book but some old. I recomend you use unit test instead integration test. Documentation is almost inexistent but you can see a great example in grails source code:

[WebFlow unit test code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-testing/src/test/groovy/grails/test/mixin/WebFlowUnitTestMixinTests.groovy)

You can see webflows with inputs, outputs, subflows, etc. (Inputs and outputs are newer that GIA book)

In examples Roeche use conversation scope, you can use flow scope instead.

Comment: The link is currently down.

Comment: Yep, my new recommendation: Do not use webflow. It's buggy and undocumented.

Comment: It looks like this might be the current link: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/9560f8275abb76e3ba0afe94967ee196768d0af6/grails-plugin-testing/src/test/groovy/grails/test/mixin/WebFlowUnitTestMixinTests.groovy